# For cabal, what does only-dependencies flag mean?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm fairly new to Haskell, and upon seeing this flag, e.g. in this [dockerfile](https://github.com/freebroccolo/docker-haskell/blob/master/examples/7.8/snap/Dockerfile), I can't ever seem to find an explanation for what it does. *"Install only the dependencies necessary to build the given packages,"* in the `cabal help install` doesn't say much to me.

If I'm not building inside a docker container, I use sandboxes. Is this flag applicable to either of these situations?

Comment: like in `cabal install --dependencies-only`? - It just means: look at the projects `.cabal` file and install all the listed dependencies (the needed packages to compile the code)

Comment: What's then the difference between it and simply running `cabal install`, which has worked for me so far?

Comment: `cabal install` will install the library(project) itself too ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> For cabal, what does only-dependencies flag mean?

It can be spelled as both `--dependencies-only` and `--only-dependencies` and it simply means that it will install all, and only, the dependencies the specific package requires (without installing or building the packages themselves). Note that by default tests and benchmark dependencies will not be installed; for them you need to add `--enable-tests` and `--enable-benchmarks` respectively.

> Is this flag applicable to either of these situations?

Yes, this can be used just fine with cabal sandboxes as well as without.

> What's then the difference between it and simply running cabal install, which has worked for me so far?

`cabal install` will install both those dependencies and the packages themselves. Same for `cabal build`. `cabal install --only-dependencies` will only install the dependencies those packages require.